# Python notification

Tags: python, notifications

Is there a way for me to bring what is inside of 'a' into the message?

```
a = print("You have shown",top1.value,"and",top2.value)
notification.notify(title="Facial Expression" , message =" ", app_icon=None, timeout=3,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print() method does not return a value.

```
a = "You have shown " + top1.value + " and " + top2.value
print(a)
notification.notify(title="Facial Expression", message=a, app_icon=None, timeout=3,)
```

Comment: I have tested your codes and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!